# Unable to set content_type for native_mailer in Monolog's yaml configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I'm currently trying to use Monolog to email me uncaught exceptions formatted as HTML using PHP's native mailer. I receive the emails just fine but the HTML is in plain text, it seems the content type is set to `text/plain` and I am unable to set the content_type to `text/html` via the yaml configuration.

My `monolog.yaml` looks like this:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        console:
            type:   console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
        system_logger:
            type: native_mailer
            from_email: 'Some email here'
            to_email: 'my_email_address@test.com'
            subject: 'Uncaught exception'
            formatter: monolog.formatter.html
            level: error
            content_type: text/html   # this is not supported?
```

Looking at Monolog's `NativeMailerHandler`, it does have a `setContentType` function, but how do I access this via the yaml configuration?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://symfony.com/doc/master/logging/monolog_email.html? It uses `type: swift_mailer` instead of `native_mailer`

Comment: @nico-haase I've seen that link yes but I prefer to use `native_mailer` for this use-case, it seems weird that I'm unable to set the content_type in the yaml while it is possible in the `NativeMailerHandler` class.

Comment: As explained in [this Github issue](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/272), MonologBundle doesn't support the `content_type` nor a `headers` keys with [native_mail](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php#L469-L475) handler. When looking at the MonologBundle source code, I think it's not possible to use HTML with native_mail yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After (unsuccessfully) trying for some time to set the `content_type` to `html/text` for the `native_mailer`, I just switched to the `swift_mailer` instead.

Comment: Is your `swift_mailer` configuration the exact same as the `native_mailer` one?

Comment: @AnthonyB No, I used the configuration provided by the Symfony documentation. It's at the bottom of the link Nico Haase provided.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'd already tried this configuration for swift_mailer, but the sendmail usage was probably wrong because only native_mailer sends me an email. Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 0):

When using `native_mailer`, you can directly set the Content-Type header to achieve the desired output, since 2019.

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    your_handler:
      headers:
        - "Content-Type: text/html"
```